# Fullcalendar add new event by clicking using bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is there any way to mimic google calendar function such as adding new event by clicking on weekly and daily view?

I tried looking at other examples but still having a hard time. An jsfiddle example would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this code example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  editable: true,
    selectable: true,
  //header and other values
  select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      endtime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,'h:mm tt');
      starttime = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
      var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
      $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
      $('#createEventModal #apptEndTime').val(end);
      $('#createEventModal #apptAllDay').val(allDay);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
   }
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
// We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
  e.preventDefault();

  doSubmit();
});

function doSubmit(){
$("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
  console.log($('#apptStartTime').val());
  console.log($('#apptEndTime').val());
  console.log($('#apptAllDay').val());
  alert("form submitted");

  $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    {
        title: $('#patientName').val(),
        start: new Date($('#apptStartTime').val()),
        end: new Date($('#apptEndTime').val()),
        allDay: ($('#apptAllDay').val() == "true"),
    },
    true);
 }
});
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/AzmJv/2074/